# Rollback() but the query still getting new value

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I use .NET 5 with EF Core 5.0.5 and Pomelo Mysql 5.00.

I test a transaction with this code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestTransaction()
{
    var listTester = await _context.Tester.ToListAsync();
    using var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            listTester.ForEach(x =>
            {
                x.Value += i;
            });
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        transaction.Rollback();
        var newLister = await _context.Tester.ToListAsync();
        return Ok(newLister);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // TODO: Handle 
        return BadRequest("Data failed");
    }
}
```

I have data

```
new Tester(){ Name = "test", Value = 0 }
```

when the code finished I received List

```
new Tester(){ Name = "test", Value = 15 }
```

The data inside mysql db still 0 because the data rolled back, but on

```
var newLister = await _context.Tester.ToListAsync();
```

it still got `Value = 15`.

Why did the `rollBack()` didn't affect the current data?

Note: I want to test `SaveChanges()` on each loop, I know I could place `SaveChanges` after the loop done. But I just want to test it as well ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to clear cached entities. EF will not reload entities which are already modified. EF Core 5 has this possibility:

```cs
...
transaction.Rollback();
_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `_context.Database.UseTransaction(transaction)`

This will force EF to use the declared transaction, instead of implicitly creating an internal transaction each time you call `_context.SaveChanges()`.

Documentation: [Entity Framework Transactions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/transaction-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Note: Each transaction created internally will commit the changes once saved, hence the need to use your transaction.